# Can MongoDbMessageStore be shared between few JVMs?

Tags: spring-integration

Assuming there are few instances (JVMs) of an application with some `spring-integration` flow on board. One of the queue channels in the flow uses a `MongoDbMessageStore` to persist messages. 
Can this message store be shared between the running instances? E.g. if it's added a message on one instance will it show up on another instance automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, instance of `MessageStore` as any object can be shared. If you are implying multiple instance of application as multiple JVM instances, then of course you can not share the same instance of `MessageStore`, but. . . if instance of `MessageStore` in each application instance (JVM) points to the same storage then you are effectively sharing it. 
MessageStore is just a facade to a shared storage.

Comment: yes I meant sharing between different JVMs. So there should be no synchronisation or caching issues? Does it mean that each JVM can guaranteed atomically process only one message and no further instances will process the same message?